# Update a String in Java

Tags: java

How can I update oldString to newString in Java? Below are given strings.

```
oldString = "03\/29\/2019"
newString = "03\/29\/2020"
```

I have tried but I think JAVA is unable to update strings which contains special character.

Comment: `oldString = newString;`?

Comment: Please help us help you by showing the code you tried to use for the update. Then maybe we can see why java was complaining.

Comment: The forward slash (/) does not require escaping. Remove the back slash (\\) supplied to each forward slash. If you want the back slash to actually be in the string then you need to use 'double back slash' (\\\).

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: And since you were asked to do show your code an hour ago: https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'special' character in the string examples you show **other than** the Back-Slash character (\). The forward-slash (/) does not require escaping however the back-slash does since it is considered, an [Escape Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html), for example:

Declare and initialize the **oldString** string variable with characters that contain Forward-Slashes (/):

```
String oldString = "03/29/2019";
```

Declare and initialize the **oldString** string variable with characters that contain Back-Slashes (\):

```
String oldString = "03\\29\\2019";
```

To represent the escape character (\) within a string you need to ***escape it*** as well. If there is more than one Back-Slash within a string then each Back-Slash needs to be escaped, for example if you want to have a double Back-Slash between Month, Day, and Year then:

```
String oldString = "03\\\\29\\\\2019";
System.out.println(oldString);
```

would display `03\\29\\2019` within the console window.

It is best to just use Forward-Slashes (/) for date representation.

Quotation marks ( **"** ) also need to be escaped in order to be represented within a String, for example:

```
String oldString = "\"03/29/2019\"";
System.out.println(oldString);
```

would display `"03/29/2019"` within the console window.